# How to use stage.addEventListener in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have used some `stage.addEventListener` in my project in as3 but I want those stage events only to work on a specific frame. can I put the stage on false or something? how can I avoid that when I click a button on the stage other things/objects doesn't start doing things because they are related to the `stage.addEventListener`, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you can check the frame, like:

```
if(currentFrame == 'SpecificFrame')
{
    //codeHere
}
```

A better way would to be to **remove** the event with `removeEventListener` when changing frames.

However, all children are part of the stage, so you you cannot prevent Objects related to the stage not to be effected by the Event.  You can, however, make an Object the same size as the stage below all other Objects (through code, `swapChildren` or `setChildIndex`).

Comment: if I use stage.currentFrame I get this error: not right  static flash.display:Stage.

Comment: @user2852398 Remove `stage.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something on a particular frame, Use following code.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, chkit);

function chkit(event:Event):void{
    if (currentFrame == 90){
    trace("Reached"); // whatever you want to be done on reaching particular frame
    }
    else{
     //things that should be done when particular frame is not reached
    }
}
```